# Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user "username" (Not using UNIX account)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, knex.js

The problem occurs with the following command:

`knex --knexfile config/db/knexfile.js migrate:latest`

I get the following error:

```
Knex:warning - Pool2 - Error: Pool was destroyed
Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user "dennis"
Knex:Error Pool2 - error: password authentication failed for user "dennis"
Error: Pool was destroyed
    at Pool._destroyPool (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/pool2/lib/pool.js:560:20)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/pool2/lib/pool.js:474:18)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/pool2/lib/pool.js:517:17)
    at tryCatcher (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise.errorAdapter [as _rejectionHandler0] (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeify.js:35:34)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:558:21)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:681:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/dennis/projects/amgen-sites/data-api/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:570:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:550:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:529:5)
```

It seems like it is not using my UNIX account and instead trying to authenticate using username/password.

I have tried the following solutions:

- Update `pg` to the latest
- Update `knex` to the latest
- replace the method to trust from:

  `# IPv4 local connections: host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust`
- replace the connection string from `[db name]` to `[postgres://[db name]`:

  ```
  connection: {
    database: 'postgres://data-api-dev',
    user:     '',
    password: ''
  },
  ```

How to I get it to use my UNIX account?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 using Node v6.3.1.

Here are my installed packages:

```
├── bluebird@2.10.2
├── body-parser@1.15.2
├── bookshelf@0.10.0
├── chai@3.5.0
├── chai-as-promised@5.3.0
├── colors@1.1.2
├── convict@1.4.0
├── cors@2.7.1
├── express@4.14.0
├── gulp@4.0.0-alpha.2 (git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#d8f5c90a0622d19ef1943a2a3d02dc50e3c853e7)
├── gulp-exit@0.0.2
├── gulp-mocha@2.2.0
├── gulp-nodemon@2.1.0
├── gulp-using@0.1.0
├── jsonwebtoken@5.7.0
├── knex@0.11.10
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── pg@6.1.0
├── request-promise@0.4.3
├── sinon@1.17.5
├── sinon-as-promised@4.0.2
├── sinon-chai@2.8.0
├── supertest@1.2.0
└── validator@4.9.0
```

Comment: hello, AFAIK knex just passes the config objet to the pg library: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client if so, it's up to pg to offer some way to use unix sockets instead tcp connections.

Comment: @Sombriks You were correct, this was a postgresql config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that renaming the method from `md5` to `trust` was the correct solution. I forgot to restart the postgresql service after making the changes, thus it did not work the first time.